# How to create an sqlite3 .db file with static data on Windows?

Tags: javascript, cordova, sqlite, cordova-plugins

I am creating hybrid app to display some places history of India in Cordova. I am using `sqlite-plugin` in Cordova.

I want to use pre-populated database file with all the data. But I don't know how to how to create `databaseName.db` file so that I can directly import (use) it in my application.

Comment: There is a plugin that helps you do that, or a tutorial. Search for it, I have seen this question asked. Do a search. http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/ Google: [sqlite prepopulate cordova](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite+prepopulate+cordova)

Comment: Here is one [The simple way to add a prepopulated SQLite DB](http://hansjar.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-easily-add-prepopulated-sqlite.html)

Comment: thanks for the above link , but my question was "How to create .db file in windows" so that I can use .db file in my app.

Comment: SQLite files are portable. According to the documentation, you should be able to move them between platforms. https://www.sqlite.org/different.html The only difference might be the [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) nature of the supporting chip. That is to say, if the mobile device is ARM and the windows PC is Pentium, the endian order of the data may not allow this. To be clear, the best you might be able to do is write SQL and the populate the database from a copy on a similar device. That is, pre-populate on an Android, and then copy that file to your final release.

Comment: Unfortunately the Cordova-sqlite-storage plugin that I maintain does not yet support pre-populated databases for Windows. I am planning to add this functionality within the next 1-2 weeks or so.

Comment: Thanks JesseMonory650 , I got another solution SQLite Manager add-ons for Firefox , from which I created database  file with hard coded data. and use that database file using cordova sqlite plugin. 

I got solution from this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154173/prepopulate-sqlite-db-in-sencha-touch-cordova-project

Comment: Thanks @brodybits . but I found one link 

https://github.com/Yoinbol/SqlitePopulated
inside   cordova/plugin/com.phonegap.plugins.sqlite/www/SQLitePlugin.js  there is a method importPrepopulatedDatabase to import database.

Comment: Happy to hear. You can also add and accept your own answer.

Comment: @brodybits . sorry to disturbed you again , but the code was too old and now there is no such method window.sqlitePlugin.importPrepopulatedDatabase() inside SQLitePlugin.js to import database file .

Comment: I will work on the functionality in the next 1-2 weeks.

Comment: Thanks @brodybits for your valuable reply.

Comment: I just published a version at https://github.com/brodybits/cordova-sqlite-extras that supports the pre-populated database for Windows ("Universal"). Unfortunately the dbcopy at https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy does not support Windows, or at least not yet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lot of search and try , I got answer.

For creating sqlite3 database file I have used following tool and created db with hard coded data. 
http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/

Suppose , I created testDatabase.db and copied it in cordova www folder.
then install plugin dbcopy(https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy) to copy testDatabase.db to device /data/data/database folder

use `window.plugins.sqlDB.copy("testDatabase.db", success,error);` in deviceready success function.

then install sqlite plugin from https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage , and used following code inside success function of window.plugins.sqlDB.copy

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "testDatabase.db",createFromLocation =1 });
```